# How would you convert the following 32-bit IEEE floating-point to decimal form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, number-systems, floating-point

I have got -1.101 1100 1011 1010 1001 1000 * 2^(9)

How can I convert this to decimal form?

Comment: Multiply each digit by successive powers of $2$.

Comment: @AvZ That works if it is *not* IEEE floating-point form.

Answer (score 0):

multiplying by $2^9$ gets you $-101 1100 10.1010011000$ in binary. Hence you want is minus $2^{10}+2^8+2^7+2^6+2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\frac{1}{2^7}=1474.64920594$.

Final answer is then: $-1474.64920594$